# how to use same slug for different post within same post type but have different category name in the permalink in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use single category in the permalink and want to have multiple post having same slug.

Ex.

1. mysite.com/category-1/my-post
2. mysite.com/category-2/my-post
3. mysite.com/category-3/my-post

I know that wordpress does't allow multiple post with same slug but if there is any way to work around.

I have tried by making custom post type and adding it in the slug like
mysite.com/post-type-1/my-post
but still wordpress add -2 in the slug.

is there any other way or only way for making this happen ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can add the custom slug of your post easily from your side bar of post page in WordPress dashboard permalink >>add your custom slug [image: like this]